# Dúvida com Intents

Tags: android

Eu utilizo IntentService para pegar os dados do meu Banco na internet. e estou passando os dados da classe intentservice para Activity com uso de intent. Minha duvida é quanto de dados eu posso passar via intent.

O usuário vai visualizar esses itens em uma lista infinita até o ultimo registro do banco. Esses itens estou passando para um Arraylist dentro do IntentService.

Devo gerenciar a pesquisa de acordo com o rolar da lista? Tipo limpar o o ArrayList ao rolar a lista? para não ter uma ArrayList gigantesco?

Comment: Tá meio difícil de entender sua pergunta.
*Eu utilizo IntentService para pegar os dados do meu Banco na internet*:  O que é "meu Banco na internet"?

Comment: Bando de Dados. Webservice. O meu banco de dados é externo em um webservice.

Answer (score 0):

Não é muito bom você mostrar todos os registros do banco. Muito dificilmente o usuário vai querer ver tudo, os mais importantes no contexto do app são os que você deve priorizar. O ideal é que você só mostre mais informação quando o usuário pedir.

E pra resolver esse problema, você pode criar um endpotint no seu webservice que receba como parâmetro o número de items a serem retornados. Se você tiver usando a arquitetura REST, um exemplo seria: `endereçoDoWebService/itens/10`, que retornaria os últimos 10 itens.

No Android, você adicionaria um listener ao RecyclerView, ou seja lá qual outra view você estiver usando pra mostrar os itens, e, sempre que chegar ao final do scroll, você faz uma requisição ao seu webservice pedindo mais itens e, quando eles retornarem, você os adiciona à sua lista.

O app do Facebook, por exemplo, só carrega mais informação no seu feed quando você chega no final da lista atual ou quando dá um swipe to refresh.

Comment: Blz vou fazer isso.